# Uniform random number generator in closed interval

Tags: c++, c, random, gsl

I need a unbiased uniform random number generator (of double) for c or c++ on a **closed** interval, say [0,1].

Many random number generators, such as the GSL `gsl_rng_uniform(r)`,works only in open intervals, as [0,1), but this does not fit into my case.

Al.

Comment: Integer or floating point?

Comment: Define "good" uniform random number generator... Other than "closed interval", what other properties are you looking for? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: Also why both *C* and *C++* can you pick one they are not the same and the answer is not the same either.

Comment: probability to get any real in [0,1] is zero. Hence, it is mathematically close to take a real in [0,1] or [0,1). The only difference is the '1' case, but it's probability of occurrence is null anyway.

Comment: To expand on what @ndj said, the chances of getting a random `double` exactly on the interval end are somewhere between 1 in 2^54 and 1 in 2^64. It isn't practical to generate enough random numbers to notice the difference between the open and closed intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something wrong with the concept of a closed interval unless you have integer values - since the probability of hitting the "end" of the interval is infinitesimally small. If you have an integer random number generator with a maximum value `RAND_MAX`, then you get a closed interval by computing

```
rand() / double(RAND_MAX)
```

since it will go exactly from 0 to 1 (inclusive)

If this does not give you sufficient resolution, you could consider "concatenating" multiple random numbers. Given that a double actually has a mantissa of 53 bits (plus one bit that is "always 1"), you could do this (this code assumes that RAND_MAX = 0xFFFFFFFF for readability; you can improve on it...):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double goodRand() {
  unsigned long long r;
  unsigned long long int r1, r2;
  r1 = rand();
  r2 = rand();
  r = (r1 << 22) + (r2 & 0x003FFFFF);
  return (double) r/ (double)(0x001FFFFFFFFFFFFF);
}

int main(void) {
  int i;
  double rMax = 0;
  for (i =0; i < 10000; i++) {
    double temp;
    temp = goodRand();
    rMax = (temp>rMax)?temp:rMax;
  }
  printf("max value is %lf\n", rMax);
}
```

Now you have very finely sampled random numbers with a maximum value of 1.0 (inclusive). You can make the code a bit more compact but this is the general idea...

Comment: It sounds interesting! I read that the c function rand() is produces number quite correlated, i.e. not quite random. Can I used something like  `(double)gsl_rng_uniform_int (r, N)/(double)(N-1)` and tune the precision with `N`? The doc for GSL is: [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Sampling-from-a-random-number-generator.html#Sampling-from-a-random-number-generator)

Comment: You are right - in some implementations, the lower bits of `rand()` go through a cyclic pattern which makes it 'a little bit less random'. This is why it is important to specify what randomness means for you. You could adapt the above trick to mask the lower 12 bits of the random number and repeat 3 times - this gets rid of all the "slightly nonrandom" numbers. There are other libraries of random number generators. The point I try to make: your requirement that it be possible to generate exactly `1.00000` as a number can be met only by starting with integer PRNG; in practice does it matter?

Comment: See https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MSC30-C.+Do+not+use+the+rand()+function+for+generating+pseudorandom+numbers

Answer (score 1):

What about [C++11 Random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/), for Example std::mt19937 + std::uniform_int_distribution?

```
std::mt19937 generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,1);
int number = distribution(generator);
```

Comment: I highly doubt the OP wants a uniform distribution binned to the two values 0 and 1, which is all you can get from an `int` distribution on [0, 1].

Answer (score 1):

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist{0.0, std::nextafter(1.0, 2.0)};

std::random_device r;
std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()}; 
std::mt19937 eng(seed);
double v = dist(eng); // a random double in the range 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive
```

Although it should be noted that floating point distributions typically aren't perfect in terms of rounding and the least significant bits.

Comment: It looks like uniform_real_distribution(a,b) is defined on [a,b). How does `nextafter` works?

Comment: @altroware: `nextafter` gives the next representable value after the first argument in the direction of the second argument. Thus, in this case, it gives the least `double` that is greater than one. Assuming the generator is implemented with proper care for floating-point issues (not an assumption I would rely on), this causes it to potentially return values in [0, 1], inclusive, and not more.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed: it appears that in practice `uniform_real_distribution` actually already produces an inclusive range.

Comment: @EricPostpischil actually it was just rounding issues in the implementation I'm looking at, so floating point problems may be an issue. However for these specific numbers the rounding works out properly on the implementation I looked at and does produce values exactly in the range [0,1].